# MVC Url Routing Complications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a project where I want to be able to represent the following different types of URL paths/routes.

```
{controller}/{section}
{controller}/{section}/{id}
{controller}/{section}/{organization}
{controller}/{section}/{id}/{key}
{controller}/{section}/{organization}/{id}
{controller}/{section}/{organization}/{id}/{key}
```

I have specified the route mapping in **global.asax** like the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Section", // Route name
    "{controller}/{section}", // URL with parameters
    new { 
        controller = "Poll", 
        action = "Section",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "SectionMember", // Route name
    "{controller}/{section}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { 
        controller = "Poll", 
        action = "SectionMember",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "SectionOrganization", // Route name
    "{controller}/{section}/{organization}", // URL with parameters
    new { 
        controller = "Poll", 
        action = "SectionOrganization", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional 
    } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "SectionOrganizationMember", // Route name
    "{controller}/{section}/{organization}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { 
        controller = "Poll", 
        action = "SectionOrganizationMember", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional 
    } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "SectionMemberKey", // Route name
    "{controller}/{section}/{id}/{key}", // URL with parameters
    new { 
        controller = "Poll", 
        action = "SectionMemberKey", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional 
    } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "SectionOrganizationMemberKey", // Route name
    "{controller}/{section}/{organization}/{id}/{key}", // URL with parameters
    new { 
        controller = "Poll", 
        action = "SectionOrganizationMemberKey", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional 
    } // Parameter defaults
);
```

I have the following code in my controller:

```
public class PollController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Section(string section)  {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SectionMember(string section, int id) {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SectionOrganization(string section, string organization) {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SectionOrganizationMember(string section, string organization, int id) {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SectionMemberKey(string section, int id, string key) {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SectionOrganizationMemberKey(string section, string organization, int id, string key) {
        return View();
    }

}
```

There seems to be complications with the URL routing, because it keeps looking for an {id} parameter when I'm trying to hit a route that doesn't require one, and vice versa.

Does my setup show any serious overlapping, or am I completely missing something?

**Edit**

Some example URL's that I would use would be the following:

- http://mysite.com/Poll/section
- http://mysite.com/Poll/section/1234
- http://mysite.com/Poll/section/organization/
- http://mysite.com/Poll/section/1234/key
- http://mysite.com/Poll/section/organization/1234
- http://mysite.com/Poll/section/organization/1234/key

Comment: Can you give an example of a URL you would use?

Comment: The problem may be the order in which you are creating the routes. The routing engine will use the first matching route. Generally you want to place the most specific route at the top, and the more general ones at the bottom. You may need to play around with the order in which you create the routes to get it to work as you intend.

Comment: I have added sample URLS as shown above

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to some items.

- The position of routes in route config is important, it would be better if you place your routes from complex to simplest.
- If you don't have optional id, don't specify it.
- You should apply build-in route constraints, because route system don't understand which route is right when choose from `/Poll/section/1234` and `/Poll/section/organization/`.

As result your route config should look like this

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "SectionOrganizationMemberKey", // Route name
        "{controller}/{section}/{organization}/{id}/{key}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Poll", action = "SectionOrganizationMemberKey" } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "SectionOrganizationMember", // Route name
        "{controller}/{section}/{organization}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Poll", action = "SectionOrganizationMember" }, // Parameter defaults
        new { id = @"\d+" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "SectionMemberKey", // Route name
        "{controller}/{section}/{id}/{key}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Poll", action = "SectionMemberKey" } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "SectionMember", // Route name
        "{controller}/{section}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Poll", action = "SectionMember" }, // Parameter defaults
        new { id = @"\d+" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "SectionOrganization", // Route name
        "{controller}/{section}/{organization}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Poll", action = "SectionOrganization" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Section", // Route name
        "{controller}/{section}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Poll", action = "Section" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

I have tested it, work fine.

Comment: +1: nice assumption, that `id` could only be numeric and great use of constraints

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Section", // Route name
    "{controller}/{ action }", // URL with parameters
    new { 
        controller = "Poll", 
        action = "Section"

    } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "SectionMember", // Route name
    "{controller}/{ action }/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { 
        controller = "Poll", 
        action = "SectionMember",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "SectionOrganization", // Route name
    "{controller}/{ action }/{organization}", // URL with parameters
    new { 
        controller = "Poll", 
        action = "SectionOrganization",
 organization= UrlParameter.Optional 
    } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "SectionOrganizationMember", // Route name
    "{controller}/{ action }/{organization}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { 
        controller = "Poll", 
        action = "SectionOrganizationMember", 
        organization= UrlParameter.Optional ,
        id = UrlParameter.Optional 
    } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "SectionMemberKey", // Route name
    "{controller}/{ action }/{id}/{key}", // URL with parameters
    new { 
        controller = "Poll", 
        action = "SectionMemberKey", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional,
        key = UrlParameter.Optional
    } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "SectionOrganizationMemberKey", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action }/{organization}/{id}/{key}", // URL with parameters
    new { 
        controller = "Poll", 
        action = "SectionOrganizationMemberKey", 
organization= UrlParameter.Optional ,
        id = UrlParameter.Optional,
key = UrlParameter.Optional

    } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: Where is the `section`? `section` and `action` are different here. `section` is a variable, not a name of an action

Comment: If you look at the controller, Section is the first action on the controller.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to constraints, say, if it's difficult to find a suitable constraint, one thing you can do is use *mixed segments*, i.e. add some prefix to one of them, for example, use `member-{id}` instead of `{id}`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Section", // Route name
    "{controller}/{section}", // URL with parameters
    new
    {
        controller = "Poll",
        action = "Section",
    } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "SectionMember", // Route name
    "{controller}/{section}/member-{id}", // URL with parameters
    new
    {
        controller = "Poll",
        action = "SectionMember",
    } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "SectionOrganization", // Route name
    "{controller}/{section}/{organization}", // URL with parameters
    new
    {
        controller = "Poll",
        action = "SectionOrganization",
    } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "SectionOrganizationMember", // Route name
    "{controller}/{section}/{organization}/member-{id}", // URL with parameters
    new
    {
        controller = "Poll",
        action = "SectionOrganizationMember",
    } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "SectionMemberKey", // Route name
    "{controller}/{section}/member-{id}/{key}", // URL with parameters
    new
    {
        controller = "Poll",
        action = "SectionMemberKey",
    } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "SectionOrganizationMemberKey", // Route name
    "{controller}/{section}/{organization}/member-{id}/{key}", // URL with parameters
    new
    {
        controller = "Poll",
        action = "SectionOrganizationMemberKey",
    } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Obviously you'll get the following routes instead:

1. http://mysite.com/Poll/section
2. http://mysite.com/Poll/section/member-1234
3. http://mysite.com/Poll/section/organization/
4. http://mysite.com/Poll/section/member-1234/key
5. http://mysite.com/Poll/section/organization/member-1234
6. http://mysite.com/Poll/section/organization/member-1234/key

Tested it, should work as stated